# Can the parallel axis theorem be applied to find the moment of inertia about a new center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, collision, moment-of-inertia

Consider a particle of mass m that collides and sticks to a rod of mass M hanging from a pivot at some distance d from the center of mass of the rod. The result of such a collision would alter the center of mass of the rod, along with the moment of inertia.

I understand the trivial case of the parallel axis theorem is to derive the moment of inertia about the end of a rod using it's moment of inertia for the center of mass, and the theorem only works when starting with the moment of inertia about the center of mass.

I have the following inquiry:

Given the new center of mass, call it CM',  and as a result the distance between the old and new center of mass, can one recover the moment of inertia about the new center of mass through the following formula?

[image]

If so, can the following formula then be applied to find the moment of inertia about the pivot point of the rod?

[image]

My suspicion is, as long as the first equation is valid, the second equation is valid.

Comment: The notion of a _new_ center of mass is a bit confusing. The _combined_ center of mass was always there, as well as each _individual_ center of mass. As far as the combined center of mass nothing changes before or after the impact.

Comment: From where are you measuring the quantity (CM')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first equation is missing a term. You are summing up MMOI about the combined COM so you need the parallem axis theorem for both the rod and the particle

$$ \begin{aligned} I_c' & = I_c^{\rm rod} + M (\tfrac{L}{2} - c')^2 +   m ( d - c')^2 \\
\end{aligned} \tag{1}$$

where $I_c^{\rm rod} = \tfrac{M}{12} L^2$, $d$ is the distance of the particle from the pivot, and $c'$ is the combined center of mass distance from the pivot. Of course the two are related since $c' (M+m) = M \tfrac{L}{2} + m d$.

So if we elimitate $d$ from (1) and express it in terms of the new COM it is

$$ \begin{aligned} I_c' & = I_c^{\rm rod} + (M+m) \tfrac{M}{m} \left( \tfrac{L}{2} - c' \right)^2 \\
\end{aligned} \tag{2}$$

If you go the other way and eliminate $c'$ from (1) then you have

$$ \begin{aligned} I_c' & = I_c^{\rm rod} + \tfrac{M m}{M+m} \left( \tfrac{L}{2} - d \right)^2 \\
\end{aligned} \tag{3}$$

Either way, once $I_c'$ is evaluated, then the parallel axis theorem is indeed used to transfer to the pivot

$$ \begin{aligned} I_R' & = I_c' + (M+m) \left( c' \right)^2 \\
 & = I_c' + (M+m) \left( \tfrac{M \tfrac{L}{2} + m d}{M + m} \right)^2 \\
 & = I_c' + \tfrac{1}{M+m} \left( M \tfrac{L}{2} + m d \right)^2
\end{aligned} \tag{4}$$

Here $I_R'$ is the MMOI of the combined system (and hence the ') at the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

If the original CM is a distance (d) from the pivot, then the original (I) is (1/12)M$L^2$ + M$d^2$.  If (m) strikes the rod at a distance (x) from the pivot, then the new (I) is (1/12)M$L^2$ + M$d^2$ + m$x^2$. I know this does not answer your question, but why complicate the problem?

Comment: You are right - I discussed this with my professor and realized I had a complete misconception of moments of inertia and when it is appropriate to simply add them - thank you!